# JavaFX GUI stuck when DataInputStream is in while loop

Tags: java, javafx, connection-string, fxml

I've been trying to figure it out for some time,

I'm trying to write a chat - server app, just for learning.
I have an obstacle that I cannot understand,

The while loop inside of the GUI class freeze, but just when it trying to read:

```
public void run(){
    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        do {
            try {
                msg = getFromServer.readUTF(); // <--- freeze GUI
                chatWindow.appendText(msg);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } while (true);
    });
}
```

You can see that it's running in a thread, but i did try to run it in other ways...

Only the DataInputStream make it stuck,

```
msg = getFromServer.readUTF();
```

And this it the methud that it's coming from:

```
public void connectToServer(){
    try {
        serverConectionState = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 6789);
        getFromServer = new DataInputStream(serverConectionState.getInputStream());
        sendToServer = new DataOutputStream(serverConectionState.getOutputStream());
        onlineOffline.setText("Online");
        onlineOffline.setTextFill(javafx.scene.paint.Color.web("#0076a3"));
    } catch (IOException ex){
        chatWindow.appendText("server connection fail\n");
    }
}
```

This class, is the Controller.class - if it's make any diffrent.

My first question in stackoverflow, after a lot of help from the community.

Thanks in advance

Comment: as suggested in the answers below , you ll have to use the `Platform.runLater()` only when you want to Update the UI and not doing business logic or data manipulation in those threads. So , in your example , you should call a `Runnable` and when the runnable finishes the job it should update the UI with `Platform.runLater()` . Also note that for large applications better use an ExecutorService , rather than spawning threads on demand

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming the `run` method you showed is part of a `Runnable` that is executed in a background thread.

You are running the entire loop on the FX Application Thread (by using `Platform.runLater()`). So you block that thread and prevent it from repainting. You should run only the UI updates on the FX Application Thread:

```
public void run(){
    do {
        try {
            String msg = getFromServer.readUTF(); // <--- freeze GUI
            Platform.runLater(() -> chatWindow.appendText(msg));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } while (true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks James, I know that it's for updating the textField, but my issue is with:  String msg = getFromServer.readUTF();                                          even if I won't append text, I still have the GUI freeze. And yeah, and bdw, implements Runnable in Controller, is that OK? This may freeze the GUI??

Comment: Are you running this in a background thread? Perhaps you can edit your code to show where this is actually getting invoked. Are you saying that if you remove `chatWindow.appendText(...)` *and* remove the `Platform.runLater(...)` entirely, it still blocks the GUI?

Comment: Cheers, thanks again, i updated the code, if you can take a look - https://github.com/adamdelarosa/Chat_client/blob/master/src/sample/Controller.java

Comment: James, JAMES!! Thanks so much!!! Solved!! (: Ill read more about Threads.. Newbie!!

Answer (score 3):

instead of using platform.runlater you should use java [task](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html), so that you can run the code in different thread, without freezing the UI thread

Comment: Thanks Sijo! My problem was that I add iThread.run() instead of iThread.start() But pretty sure it's could have been solved with your solution too.